# Conditionally load js file based on Wordpress theme file

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How do I determine if a Wordpress theme file is called?  For example, everytime archive.php is loaded, I want to conditionally add a js file to the footer.

I am currently using something like this in functions.php to load the global js.  How do I adjust so additional js is loaded depending on the Wordpress file called?

```
//Use Google CDN to load jQuery
function use_google_jquery() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        // comment out the next two lines to load the local copy of jQuery
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js', false, '1.7.2', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

        // load a JS file from my theme: js/default.js
        wp_enqueue_script('my_script', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/default.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);      
    }   }   add_action('init', 'use_google_jquery');
```

EDIT & NOTE:  [JS on Specific Wordpress Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482521/how-do-i-load-jquery-for-only-one-specific-page-in-my-wordpress-theme) works for a given page but I am looking for a given template file such as archive.php AND to be loaded in the footer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following functions is_single(), is_archive(), is_page(), is_home()